# How to get Value Counts in Date Time Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, group-by, time-series

I have the following data frame from where I want to get the value counts for each weekday, i.e., no. of observations on Monday(1), Tuesday(2), etc. I wrote a code but I am getting an error.

**DataFrame**

```
rowId   UserId  Name    Date                    Class   TagBased
1       1      Teacher  2009-09-30T15:17:50.660     3   False
2       3      Teacher  2009-09-30T15:17:50.690     3   False
3       13     Teacher  2009-09-30T15:17:50.690     3   False
4       14     Teacher  2009-09-30T15:17:50.690     3   False
5       22     Teacher  2009-09-30T15:17:50.690     3   False
```

**Code**

```
weekdays = {}

for index,row in df_Badge.iterrows():
  weekdays[row['Date'].isoweekday()] = weekdays.get[row['Date'].isoweekday(),0]+1
  
weekdays
```

**Error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-959273f80e23> in <module>()
      2 
      3 for index,row in df_Badge.iterrows():
----> 4   weekdays[row['Date'].isoweekday()] = weekdays.get[row['Date'].isoweekday(),0]+1
      5 
      6 weekdays

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

**Expected Output**

```
{1:10,2:34,3:2,4:55,5:11,6:1,7:99}
```

**Note**: Output is preferred if it is in the form of value counts and not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.Date.dt.day_name().value_counts()
```

Your sample data would give:

```
Wednesday    5
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can you suggest how can I plot a bar graph in the next step?

Comment: Chain that with a `plot.bar()`?